# Simple game of Old Maid, not so simple?

Tags: vb.net

Fair warning, I am going to post my entire code for player 1 just because I'm not sure what is needed in order to proceed. I am in desperate need for help. There are 49 cards, and player 1 will be getting 16. When I hit deal, there are 16 cards displayed for the user.

**My question is: How do I check these 16 cards for doubles and then remove those cards and put them in a discard pile?**

```
Public Class DeckOfCardsTest
    Dim playercards As Integer = 16
    Dim playermatches As Integer
    Dim comp1cards As Integer = 16
    Dim comp1matches As Integer
    Dim comp2cards As Integer = 17
    Dim comp2matches As Integer


    Private deck As New DeckOfCards() ' create the deck of cards




Public Class DeckOfCards
    Private Const NUMBER_OF_CARDS As Integer = 49 ' number of cards
   Private deck(NUMBER_OF_CARDS - 1) As Card ' array of Card objects
   Private currentCard As Integer ' index of next Card to be dealt
   Private Shared randomNumbers As New Random() ' random number generator

   ' constructor fills deck of Cards
   Public Sub New()
      Dim faces() As String = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
         "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"}
      Dim suits() As String = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"}
        currentCard = 0 ' set currentCard so first Card dealt is deck(0)



      ' populate deck array with Card objects
        For count = 0 To deck.GetUpperBound(0)
            deck(count) = New Card(faces(count Mod 13), suits(count \ 13))
        Next
    End Sub ' New


    ' shuffle deck of Cards with simple one-pass algorithm
    Public Sub Shuffle()
        ' after shuffling, dealing should start at deck(0) again
        currentCard = 0 ' reinitialize currentCard

        ' for each Card, pick another random Card and swap them
        For first = 0 To deck.GetUpperBound(0)
            ' select a random number between 0 and 51
            Dim second As Integer = randomNumbers.Next(NUMBER_OF_CARDS)

            ' swap current Card with randomly selected Card
            Dim temp As Card = deck(first) ' store copy of deck(first)
            deck(first) = deck(second) ' move deck(second) to deck(first)
            deck(second) = temp ' move original deck(first) to deck(second)
        Next
    End Sub ' Shuffle

    ' deal one Card
    Public Function DealCard() As Card
        ' determine whether Cards remain to be dealt
        If currentCard <= deck.GetUpperBound(0) Then
            Dim lastCard As Integer = currentCard ' store current card number
            currentCard += 1 ' increment current card number 
            Return deck(lastCard)
        Else
            Return Nothing ' no more cards to deal
        End If



    End Function ' DealCard


End Class ' DeckOfCards
```

How do I get this List(Of Card) to work in my code?

```
Dim Cards As List(Of Card) 'Players hand

If Cards.Select(Function(x) x.Value).Distinct.Count < Cards.Count Then
    'there are some duplicates in the list
    Dim duplicates = Cards.GroupBy(Function(x) x.Value).Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key).ToList
    For Each i In duplicates
        Debug.WriteLine("Card value " + i.ToString + " is a match")
    Next
End If
```

Here are the errors:

```
Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Select' can be called with these arguments: Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of Card, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Nested function does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 'System.Func(Of Card, Integer, TResult)'.
Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of Card, Integer, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error. Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of Card, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': 'Value' is not a member of 'DeckOfCardsTest.Card'. Extension method 'Public Function Select(Of TResult)(selector As System.Func(Of Card, TResult)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of TResult)' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable': Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error. 

Error   2   Data type(s) of the type parameter(s) in extension method 'Public Function GroupBy(Of TKey)(keySelector As System.Func(Of Card, TKey)) As System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(Of TKey, Card))' defined in 'System.Linq.Enumerable' cannot be inferred from these arguments. Specifying the data type(s) explicitly might correct this error.

Error   3   'Value' is not a member of 'DeckOfCardsTest.Card'.

Error   4   Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable(Of DeckOfCardsTest.Card)'. 

Error   5   Option Strict On disallows late binding.
```

Comment: You would probably benefit from reading this article on enumerations: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Probably not that important to your particular use case, but your shuffle algorithm is biased (i.e. it does not produce all 52! different orderings with equal likelihood). Have a look at the Fisher-Yates shuffle for a correct, unbiased shuffle implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Old Maid, so please excuse my ignorance.

If I understand your question correctly, you want to check the player's hand, remove doubles, and place them in a discard pile?

If that's the case, your Deck object will need to have another array (or preferably a list) of Card object to represent the discard pile.  Then, after you deal the cards, loop through each card in the player's hand and compare it to every other card (not including itself).  Since Card is an object, if two cards are identical, they will point to the same object.  Make a note of the indexes of the identical cards, then add them to your discard pile and remove them from the player's hand.

EDIT: Based on your code update, this is what I would do.  I didn't check the syntax but I think it's correct.  If not, let me know and I will fix it.

```
Dim Cards As New List(Of Card) 'Players hand
Dim discardPile As New List(Of Card) ' discard pile

For i As Integer = 1 to 16
   Cards.Add(deck.DealCard())
Next i

If Cards.Select(Function(x) x).Distinct.Count < Cards.Count Then
'there are some duplicates in the list
    Dim duplicates As List(Of Card) = Cards.GroupBy(Function(x) x.GwtValue).Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1).SelectMany(Function(g) g.ToArray).ToList

    ' This part adds the duplicates to the discard pile
    discardPile.AddRange(duplicates)
    ' This is the part that would remove the duplicates from the player's hand       
    Cards.RemoveAll(Function(y) duplicates.Contains(y))

End If
```

Comment: Well I can drop the discard pile, as long as I remove it from the list. but can you help me with the code aspect? I honestly hit a wall completely. I have found this List(Of Card) code, and added it to my main post. How to I edit it to work in my code?

Comment: I see that you are using LINQ, so it should be pretty easy then.  Check my updated post.

Comment: Thanks for the continued help, I really appreciate your time. I pasted that code you gave me in my "Deal button" code. I got a slew of errors. Am I putting it in the wrong spot? I added the error in my main post since it's so long

Comment: Most of the errors are because you have Option Strict on and you did not strongly type your duplicates list.  One error is because your Card class has no property called "Value" yet you refer to "Value" in your code.

Comment: I'm getting close! I changed this line to Dim duplicates As List(Of Card) = Cards.GroupBy(Function(x) x.GetValue).Where(Function(g) g.Count > 1).Select(Function(g) g.Key).ToList.. changing Value to GetValue. Now the only error I get is "Error 1 Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Integer)' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of DeckOfCardsTest.Card)'." THANKS!!

Comment: You are getting that error because you are selecting the Key, which is an Integer.  Just select the entire object instead (so g instead of g.Key in your example)

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and I wish it would help me out by telling me how to fix the problem like it does in some cases. I tried many different scenarios, like g.All for example. All of them have errors. If I just do Select(Function(g) g).ToList I get an error "Value of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of System.Linq.IGrouping(Of Integer, DeckOfCardsTest.Card))' cannot be converted to 'System.Collections.Generic.List(Of DeckOfCardsTest.Card)'."

Comment: If I change it to Select(Function(g).ToList I get a host of errors too. Programming is so difficult, I just can't wrap my head around it sometimes. Doing anything to get around this error, then I can finish the rest of the program up by myself, I know I can!!

Comment: Thank you, fix one thing, then another pops up. Ugh!! Now the program crashes when the deal button is clicked. Warning 1 Variable 'Cards' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: Well, duh...you never assigned anything to the Cards variable.

Comment: ha.. I'm sorry. I did so much work on this that I think my head mind might not be working anymore. How do I assign it? Then you will be done with for me good! Apologies.

Comment: When you deal your cards, you need to add them to your Cards list.  See my answer.

Comment: @user2382959 "Fix one thing, then another pops up" -> Such is programming

Comment: @Douglas Barbin Now the same error is displaying for this portion of the code  Cards.Add(deck.DealCard()).. Programming is so painful. I'm sorry you got dragged into this. Why does this program have such a problem with Cards?!? Variable 'Cards' is used before it has been assigned a value. A null reference exception could result at runtime.

Comment: I would bet my life that you have "Dim Cards as List(Of Card)" and it should be "Dim Cards As NEW List(Of Card)" instead.

Comment: @DouglasBarbin I'm sorry, you are right. I changed that and now they are displaying, but as you see here it removed 1 card for some reason, but none of the doubles https://imageshack.us/scaled/large/40/cardsq.jpg